# Why use CRC of uncompressed vs compressed data?

Tags: gzip, crc, deflate

The [Wikipedia article for Gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) says there is "an 8-byte footer, containing a CRC-32 checksum and the length of the original uncompressed data". Why do they append the CRC of the uncompressed data instead of the CRC of the compressed data?

I can only think of disadvantages such as having to process the whole data stream, running it through a Deflate algorithm, before you can verify the CRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think gzip has some freedom in how it compresses data, so calculating the crc for the compressed data could give different checksums. Calculating the crc for the uncompressed data means you have the same crc compressed, decompressed, compressed with a different algorithm.

And in the end, what you care about is that the decompressed data is what it should be. You might have a bug in the compression or decompression algorithm; a crc for the compressed data wouldn't find that.

Comment: +1 Correct. A CRC on the compressed data would only detect a transmission/storage error. A CRC on the uncompressed data would detect that as well as any bugs in compression/decompression.